# GSON Json to Map<string, JSONArray>

Tags: java, android, json, gson

Нужно конвертировать Json

```
{"1":{"param1":"101","param2":"pamagiti"},"2":{"param1":"102","param2":"pozar0"}}
```

В

```
Map<String, JSONArray>
```

Таким образом чтобы ключ был 1,2 а значение {"param1":"101","param2":"pamagiti"} и {"param1":"102","param2":"pozar0"} соответственно (в виде JSONArray)

Для этого пробую вот такой код

```
    Type type = new TypeToken<HashMap<String, JSONArray>>(){}.getType();
    Map<String, JSONArray> myMap = new Gson().fromJson(JsonString, type);

    for (Map.Entry<String, JSONArray> param : myMap.entrySet()) {

        Log.d("com.test.application", "ID " + param.getKey() + " " +  param.getValue().toString() );
    }
```

Но JSONArray получается пустым

```
ID = 1 []
ID = 2 []
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У Вас там нет массива, а JSONArray это массив. Поэтому все пусто. У Вас сейчас структура `Map<String, Map>`